# How to add icon under angular echart title?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, echarts

How to to add icon under echart title? Here is what I tried but not able to render icon

[image]

component.ts file code

```
 constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  
 ngOnInit(){
 this.iconHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<i class="fa fa-chart-bar"></i>');
  this.costByTypeChart();
   }

costByTypeChart(){
   this.typeoptions = {
      title: {
        text: `<div [innerHTML]="iconHtml"></div>`,
        subtext: "Data not loaded yet",
        left: "center",
        top: "center",
        subtextStyle: {
          fontSize: 20,

        }
      },
      yAxis: [],
      series: []
    }
};
}
```

component.html

```
<p-card header="Cost By Type">
<div echarts [options]="typeoptions" [ngStyle]="{width: '100%',height:'100%'}"></div>
</p-card>
```

o/p I am getting

[image]

Comment: How does your template file look like? You probably just need to put `<div [innerHTML]="iconHtml"></div>` inside of the template file and not through property.

Comment: @Tony, I have added the template code

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way how innerHTML could work with external library, since you need to do the binding in the child component.

What you can do here is use a [graphic](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#graphic) component.

```js
  costByTypeChart() {
    this.typeoptions = {
      title: {
        // This won't work..
        // text: `<div [innerHTML]="iconHtml"></div>`,
        subtext: 'Data not loaded yet',
        left: 'center',
        top: 'center',
        subtextStyle: {
          fontSize: 20,
        },
      },
      graphic: {
        type: 'image',
        // but you can add an image like this
        style: {
          image: 'assets/chart-bar-solid.svg',

          x: 250,
          y: 160,
          width: 30,
        },
      },
    };
```

Just make sure to add `assets/chart-bar-solid.svg` to the assets and adjust the position of the icon.

Comment: You can play around with this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wncoeb?file=src%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.ts), if you'll have any additional questions